# Add views to a storyboard programatically

Tags: ios, ipad, uistoryboard

I'm going to explain my situation 1st so that the question is clear.  I'm using a scrollview with images in it right now.  Those images right now link to different views in a storyboard.  Instead what I'd like to do is have that image open up a new UIScrollview w/ views displayed.  These views are already in the storyboard of course without nibs.

So I'm essentially trying to display UIViews in a UIScrollView.. except I cant' initialize with nib (at least to my knowledge).

Comment: When you click on an image, is it supposed to open up the new UIScrollView in a new window?

Comment: yes.. this is somewhat similar to the way Itunes works in a way.  This works at this point.. but what I'm trying to do is get mini UIViews inside that scrollview.  Clicking on those mini UIViews would cause them to enlarge, allowing you to view the contents.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a place to setup your scrollview that is in a Storyboard use `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: I've looked at that method a little.  It seems very similar to many methods.  It sounds like I'm stuck making all my views programmaticly vs. being able to create them in the Interface builder and load them up.